# Prove that [G,G] is a normal subgroup of G.

Tags: abstract-algebra

[image]

Hi I am kinda stuck here.

I figured out a) but I am not sure how to prove b) & c).

any tips or suggestions would be very appreciated!
Thank you

Comment: Let $c\in [G,G]$ and $g\in G$. Can you find a way to write $gcg^{-1}$ so that it's obvious that it's in $[G,G]$?

Comment: @Daniel Fischer could you show me the way to write that?

Comment: Another hint: you will not, in general, be able to write $gcg^{-1}$ as a commutator, but there are other kinds of elements in $[G, G]$...

Comment: Multiplying something with a cleverly chosen $1$ is often a fruitful strategy.

Comment: @Salman such as what? I am so confused about this commutator. Where can I read more about it?

Comment: @DanielFischer hey so for c) how do i show that it's an Abelian group

Answer (score 1):

For part (c): First begin by showing that $[G,G]$ is normal in $G$ so that $\frac{G}{[G,G]}$ is defined. Then note that for any $\alpha \in \frac{G}{[G,G]}$, $\alpha=g[G,G], g \in G$. Then we note that if $g \in Z(G)$, the center of $G$, that for any $h \in G$, $[g,h]=ghg^{-1}h^{-1}=hgg^{-1}h^{-1}=e$. So, all Abelian elements of $G$ may be thought of as "living outside" of $[G,G]$, for the commutator of such a $g$ is always trivial. You should be able to finish the proof from here by considering what happens to the product of two nonAbelian elements of $G$, the product of an Abelian and nonAbelian element, and the product of Abelian elements.